# Regex-FInd a line that doesn't end width the specific pattern

Tags: grep, regular-expression

So I'm using grep and regex in order to find a list of all the processes that end with windbidd:

```
ps -ef | grep "winbindd$"
```

My question is is there a way for me to do the opposite ergo find all the lines that DON"T end with the line windbidd?

Comment: `-v, --invert-match` *Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.*

Answer (score 1):

grep -v should do exactly this. From Grep's man page:

> -v, --invert-match
>
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

For example:

```
ps -ef | grep -v 'winbindd$'
```